# Need Activemq MemoryUsage optimization - my queues are overflowing

Tags: activemq-classic

We have java based message processing system in which there are nearly 25 different queues and a topic. We have set this system at a max memory usage of 2GB and processes 40 messages per second on a normal day. This system is working fine for a couple days and then starts to spike on the memory, then reaches the limit.

In our analysis, we found the MemoryUsage holds the key for this cause and below is a leak suspect stack trace of the heap dump of one of the queue which is using nearly 50% of memory. It could be possible that higher volume message could have loaded the queue heavily. What is the optimal configuration for the MemoryUsage to be set up for this system?

```
519,955,448 (62.85%) [72] 8 org/apache/activemq/usage/MemoryUsage 0x80d8d180
519,843,456 (62.84%) [16] 2 java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList 0x80d8d210
519,843,392 (62.84%) [352] 89 array of java/lang/Object 0x822cd2e0
411,721,616 (49.77%) [72] 9 org/apache/activemq/usage/MemoryUsage 0x83833378
411,721,248 (49.77%) [16] 2 java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList 0x83835898
411,721,184 (49.77%) [8] 2 array of java/lang/Object 0x8383a730
411,718,600 (49.77%) [336] 33 org/apache/activemq/broker/region/Queue 0x83833120
411,693,720 (49.77%) [16] 2 org/apache/activemq/store/kahadb/KahaDBTransactionStore$1 0x838353e0
411,693,256 (49.77%) [24] 3 org/apache/activemq/store/kahadb/KahaDBTransactionStore 0x80d76aa0
411,689,856 (49.76%) [280] 37 org/apache/activemq/store/kahadb/KahaDBStore 0x80d74de0
358,088,168 (43.29%) [104] 14 org/apache/kahadb/journal/Journal 0x80d76790
356,119,216 (43.05%) [48] 1 java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap 0x80d773c0
356,119,168 (43.05%) [64] 16 array of java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$Segment 0x80d8e628
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to speculate too much with this limited amount of information. If your consumers fall behind, the memory will start to fill and there is nothing really you can do about it. At 40 msgs per sec, then it will go fast, I guess.

What you can do is to overflow the queue to disk after some memory limit. That would slow it down, but at least have it running during a spike.

The area itself is generally complex and as far as I know, there is no silver bullet.

Read on [cursors etc](http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html) and on [memory usage and producer flow control](http://activemq.apache.org/javalangoutofmemory.html).

Comment: Just curious to know, if growing queue is directly related to the JVM memory or hard disk space. I have read that ActiveMQ converts the incoming message into ActiveMQMessage objects and keep in memory but it also creates kahaDB store files in the hard disk to maintain the actual message content. Which one/both is correct?

Comment: Persistent messages will always be saved into the KahaDB (or whatever message store is used) to avoid message loss. However, both persistent and non persistent will also be saved into memory because it's a lot faster. Depending on your configuration, you can choose what to do when you run out of memory. I.e. use disk or block the producers.